# Drop rows based on one column values

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, outliers

I've a dataframe which looks like this:

```
        wave       mean    median        mad
0    4050.32  -0.016182 -0.011940   0.008885
1    4208.98   0.023707  0.007189   0.032585
2    4508.28   3.662293  0.001414   7.193139
3    4531.62 -15.459313 -0.001523  30.408377
4    4551.65   0.009028  0.007581   0.005247
5    4554.46   0.001861  0.010692   0.027969
6    6828.60 -10.604568 -0.000590  21.084799
7    6839.84  -0.003466 -0.001870   0.010169
8    6842.04 -32.751551 -0.002514  65.118329
9    6842.69  18.293519 -0.002158  36.385884
10   6843.66   0.006386 -0.002468   0.034995
11   6855.72   0.020803  0.000886   0.040529
```

As it's clearly evident in the above table that some of the values in the column `mad` and `median` are very big(outliers). So i want to remove the rows which have these very big values.

For example in `row3` the value of `mad` is `30.408377` which very big so i want to drop this row. I know that i can use one line
to remove these values from the columns but it doesn't removes the complete row

```
df[np.abs(df.mad-df.mad.mean()) <= (3*df.mad.std())]
```

But i want to remove the complete row.

How can i do that?

Comment: Your code should work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predicates like what you've given *will* remove entire rows. But none of your data is outside of 3 standard deviations. If you tone it down to just one standard deviation, rows are removed with your example data.

Here's an example using your data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ["wave", "mean", "median", "mad"]
data = [
    [4050.32, -0.016182, -0.011940, 0.008885],
    [4208.98, 0.023707, 0.007189, 0.032585],
    [4508.28, 3.662293, 0.001414, 7.193139],
    [4531.62, -15.459313, -0.001523, 30.408377],
    [4551.65, 0.009028, 0.007581, 0.005247],
    [4554.46, 0.001861, 0.010692, 0.027969],
    [6828.60, -10.604568, -0.000590, 21.084799],
    [6839.84, -0.003466, -0.001870, 0.010169],
    [6842.04, -32.751551, -0.002514, 65.118329],
    [6842.69, 18.293519, -0.002158, 36.385884],
    [6843.66, 0.006386, -0.002468, 0.034995],
    [6855.72, 0.020803, 0.000886, 0.040529],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data), columns=columns)
print("ORIGINAL: ")
print(df)

print()

res = df[np.abs(df['mad']-df['mad'].mean()) <= (df['mad'].std())]
print("REMOVED: ")
print(res)
```

this outputs:

```
ORIGINAL:
       wave       mean    median        mad
0   4050.32  -0.016182 -0.011940   0.008885
1   4208.98   0.023707  0.007189   0.032585
2   4508.28   3.662293  0.001414   7.193139
3   4531.62 -15.459313 -0.001523  30.408377
4   4551.65   0.009028  0.007581   0.005247
5   4554.46   0.001861  0.010692   0.027969
6   6828.60 -10.604568 -0.000590  21.084799
7   6839.84  -0.003466 -0.001870   0.010169
8   6842.04 -32.751551 -0.002514  65.118329
9   6842.69  18.293519 -0.002158  36.385884
10  6843.66   0.006386 -0.002468   0.034995
11  6855.72   0.020803  0.000886   0.040529

REMOVED:
       wave       mean    median        mad
0   4050.32  -0.016182 -0.011940   0.008885
1   4208.98   0.023707  0.007189   0.032585
2   4508.28   3.662293  0.001414   7.193139
3   4531.62 -15.459313 -0.001523  30.408377
4   4551.65   0.009028  0.007581   0.005247
5   4554.46   0.001861  0.010692   0.027969
6   6828.60 -10.604568 -0.000590  21.084799
7   6839.84  -0.003466 -0.001870   0.010169
10  6843.66   0.006386 -0.002468   0.034995
11  6855.72   0.020803  0.000886   0.040529
```

Observe that rows indexed `8` and `9` are now gone.

Be sure you're reassigning the output of `df[np.abs(df['mad']-df['mad'].mean()) <= (df['mad'].std())]` as shown above. The operation is not done in place.

Comment: Yeah i can see that but  row no. 2,3,6 are still there. The values of coumn 'mad' are still very big in comparison to others in these rows.

Comment: @GyanenderGandhar Yes, but they're still inside of one standard deviation. What are you trying to do here? What do you really want to remove? You have to define what it means to be "very big", we can't guess what that means. Note that your code *does* remove entire rows, it's just that the predicate is not satisfied in your example. I thought that was the question.

Comment: @GyanenderGandhar I should say, their difference is inside of a standard deviation of the column. Do you want to just remove all items that are outside of the first standard deviation? If you do `df['mad'] <= df['mad'].std()` instead, more items will be removed.

Comment: Yeah got your point. I used this "df['mad'] <= df['mad'].std()" but still it didn't remove some rows. why so?

Comment: Did you use my code above? You're probably not reassigning the output of `df[df['mad'] <= df['mad'].std()`. You have to do something like `new_df = df[df['mad'] <= df['mad'].std()`. The operation is not done in place, `df` is not modified (also mentioned above in answer).

Answer (score 0):

Doing `df[np.abs(df.mad-df.mad.mean()) <= (3*df.mad.std())]` will not change the dataframe.
But assign it back to `df`, so that:

```
df = df[np.abs(df.mad-df.mad.mean()) <= (3*df.mad.std())]
```